# Where to define permissions for every crud action in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I have designed a store with [Laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x) ,and used [laravel-permission 3](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/) for user management. I'd like to restrict every crud action by a definite permission (e.g. add product, delete product).
There is a short description about using wildcard permission in [Spatie](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/wildcard-permissions/), but I'm not sure about it. I don't know **where is the best place in defining these restrictions**.

Here is a route sample for creating and editing product and their middleware (restrictions by permissions).

```
Route::get('/create','Controller@create')->name('create')->middleware('permission:add product');
Route::post('/store', 'Controller@store')->name('store')->middleware('permission:add product');
Route::get('/{product}/edit', 'Controller@edit')->name('edit')->middleware('permission:edit product');
Route::patch('/{product}/update', 'Controller@update')->name('update')->middleware('permission:edit product');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that use **Laravel’s Model Policies**, you can find more information in the link below.
https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/best-practices/using-policies/

Furthermore, You can find an example of implementing a model policy with this Laravel Permissions package in this demo app:
https://github.com/drbyte/spatie-permissions-demo/blob/master/app/Policies/PostPolicy.php